# typescript interface is not mapping to response

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to map a typescript interface to my axios response. In the dev tools I see the token in the response

```
{"token":"f8ad0dc6-6092-4b26-be9b-a891aa856eef"}
```

but I get a `undefined` when I try to `console.log(token)`.

I have tried it two ways. One with just json and the other with a typescript interface.

```
await judgeApi.post<{token: string}>(`/submissions?${qs.stringify({
```

full call

```
async test() {
    try {
        await judgeApi.post<JudgeRequest>(`/submissions?${qs.stringify({
            language_id: 60,
            source_code: "cGFja2FnR29vZCBq...wbGUubmFtZSkKfQo=",
            stdin: "Sn...w"
        })}`).then(res => {
            return res.data.token
        })
    }catch (err) {
        console.log("error" + err);
    }
},
```

interface

```
interface JudgeRequest {
    token: string
}
```

testing

```
          const token = await api.test()
          console.log("token... " + token) <--- undefined.
```

However token is in the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is at runtime, during the execution, so this is not related with Typescript at all.

Here, you forgot to return the promise in your method, so you return a `Promise<void>`.

```js
async test() {
    // return the promise
    return judgeApi.post<JudgeRequest>(`/submissions?${qs.stringify({
          language_id: 60,
          source_code: "cGFja2FnR29vZCBq...wbGUubmFtZSkKfQo=",
          stdin: "Sn...w"
    })}`)
    .then(res => {
         return res.data.token
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("error" + err);
    })
},
```